# Display modal after user has shared the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to display a modal popup window *after* user clicks "Share on Facebook" then *when the users goes back to the site*, the modal popup is displayed. I know this is possible because there's a website that has it.

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuHJb.png)

The popup displayed after returning back to the page.

**Modal html:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the modal as soon as the user clicks the "Share on Facebook" button? `$('#ID_OF_SHARE_ON_FACEBOOK_BUTTON').click(function () {$('.modal').show(300); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow this step.

Add your HTML code for Modal.

Initially hide the modal with the Jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    // Profile Pic Modal.
    $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: false,
    });
});
</script>
```

Now after you call the script for sharing or like you call some function for sharing 
use the below line to show the modal.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

For example you have a function

```
<script>
    function ShareThis(){
        // You Code Here

        If(Share){  // user your condition for check if sharing has done or not.
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }

    }
</script>
```

Don't hesitate to ask me again if it doesn't help.
Also do not forget to in include the jQuery and CSS for the Modal.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Hope this link may help you for Modal

Comment: thank you for your answer and thanks for trying to make me understand this although I'm confused, what do I add at comment // you code here?

Comment: it was just an example in case you  have some code to write.

Actually i dont know that how you share anything on social network, 
If you use function for social sharing then i guess this is the way that you cab go ahead , like call your function first for sharing and then check if your content was shared success full or not and respectively you can shoe the modal with the appropriate message.

Comment: I would like you  to keep me update with your code if you get stuck anywhere.!